# CI accessing property on interface

Tags: php, laravel, interface, scrutinizer

I'm using scrutinizer to analyze my code. And almost everything has been fixed but I can't seem to fix this issue.

```
Accessing id on the interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable suggest that you code against a concrete implementation. How about adding an instanceof check?
```

I see the problem beceause it's an interface that propery does not exist, but my code works just fine. So how can I let this code pass when I analyze my code?

Thanks

**Edit**

Got the error on these lines (and some other files are almost the same)

```
$this->tracert->log(
            'users',
            $this->auth->user()->id,
            $this->auth->user()->id,
            'Login'
        );
```

The constructor of that class

```
 /**
 * @param \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard $auth
 * @param \jorenvanhocht\Tracert\Tracert $tracert
 */
public function __construct(Guard $auth, Tracert $tracert)
{
    parent::__construct($auth);
    $this->tracert = $tracert;
}
```

constructor of my base controller:

```
public function __construct(Guard $auth)
{
    $this->auth = $auth;
    $this->config = objectify(config('blogify'));
    $this->auth_user = $this->auth->check() ? $this->auth->user() : false;
}
```

The used contract https://github.com/illuminate/contracts/blob/master/Auth/Guard.php

Comment: u should use `$this->auth->user()->getAuthIdentifier()`

Comment: If a look at definition *public function log($model, $row, $user_id, $action = 'created')*, dont know why you need *$row* and *$user_id*, but ok... I changed it to `log($model, \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable $user, $action = 'created')` and in method pull $user()->getAuthIdentifier() as id

Comment: Seems like getAuthIdentifier() fixed the problem. But how would you go over fixing it on a relation like this: $this->auth->user()->role->name or on another column then the id like: $this->auth->user()->role_id ?

Comment: problem is pretty clear scrutinizer doesnt know if the attrib is in your instance. i would try to cover *problematic code* in `if ($object instanceof YourClass)`. I assume `$object = new YourClass()`.

Comment: I updated my answer with this workaround.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To fix the problem for the id of the authenticated user, you should use:

```
$this->auth->user()->getAuthIdentifier()
```

[Interface](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) consists of methods. You are accessing attribute directly. eg `$foo->id` instead of `$foo->getId()`. And you have to add new method to interface of course.

The workaround is to say to scrutinizer, that *$object is instance of desired class*.

```
if ($object instanceof MyClass) {
    //
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean, but the interface/contract that is used is core of Laravel, so any idea how to solve it without editing the core? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I would suggest to make PR on github.

Comment: mmm don't really think that that is an option. I can be wrong off course